# Xcode 8 Playground don't Running

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I have problem with Xcode.. if I want to run any playground even simple code like : print("Hello "),  it is not working,
 
some time stuck on 'running' and won't run the code,
I tried to reinstalling and delete xcode files ... 
but it's still not working
 
this is the message that appears:
 
( Failed to launch process. Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down )

[image]..

> Failed to launch process. Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0xfffffecc  )

it's last version 8.2.1(8C1002)

Comment: Same issue, tried uninstalling and removing any file related to xcode or the simulators and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Failed to launch process. Unable to lookup service com.apple.CoreSimulator.host_support: 0x3 Sierra 10.12.3 Xcode 8.2.1(8C1002)

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:-
Go to menu Xcode->Preferences->Components then select and install the most recent Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

**MyPlayground is constantly syncing to iCloud**.
Sometimes because of buggy behavior or poor connection is stucks on "Running"

Just go to:

System Preferences - Apple ID - Apps on this Mac using iCloud- iCloud Drive - Options- And then **uncheck "Playground"**

That little trick prevents syncing and resolves the frozen "Running".

[image: Prevent Playgrounds syncing]